Sparse iterarive solvers matrix-free methods preconditioners
How can I define preconditioners (SPILU,SPAI, etc.) for sparse iterative methods (TFQMR,GMRES,CGS, etc.) for the matrix-free left-hand side? I defined Ax=b using matrix-free A (with LinearOperator and matvec). Therefore, I do not have a matrix A created and kept in memory. For example, in this case, how can I build SPILU preconditioners? I saw in all the tutorials and examples that a preconditioner was created using a matrix LHS.
I created the left-hand side with matrix-free methods as follows:
def matvec(x, A, B):  
    First = B.dot(x)  
    Second = A.dot(First)  
    result = B.T.dot(Second)  
    return result

linop = LinearOperator((WWWa.shape[0], WWWa.shape[0]), 
                        matvec=lambda x: matvec(x, WWWa, Ap), 
                        rmatvec=lambda x: rmatvec(x, WWWa, Ap)
                       ) 

Sparse iterative solver can be written as follows:
l_finest = A.dot(g) 
x_gmres, info_gmres = gmres(linop, l_finest.flatten(), callback=callback, tol=tolerance, atol=0,callback_type='x')

However, when I wanted to add the preconditioner, I could not figure out how to create the preconditioner since I don't have a direct matrix for the LHS (and I don't want to get a matrix either; I have large sparse matrices with billions of elements and I just want to use matrix-vector multiplication).
